# ajax send strange data? $_POST not working the usual way

Tags: php, ajax

```
if(name.val().length > 3){
        var username=name.val();
            $.post('validate.php',{names: username},function(data){
                             //do some stuff
            });

        }
```

my php work only by using

```
$name = &$_POST['names'];
$email = &$_POST['emails'];
```

but not the usual way:

```
$name = $_POST['names'];
$email = $_POST['emails'];
```

Comment: If you remove the second line in the 'usual way', is `$name` set correctly?

Comment: Both forms might be valid in different contexts. Post more code please.

Comment: @MikeW I used $name = $_POST['names'];
 but not working

Answer (score 0):

Your POST request from JavaScript doesn't contain an `emails` field, so that's probably causing a notice. Try this code to see what's being sent:

```
if(isset($_POST['names'])) {
    echo 'Names: ' . $_POST['names'] . "\n";
}

if(isset($_POST['emails'])) {
    echo 'Emails: ' . $_POST['emails'] . "\n";
}
```

(It's always a good idea to check that variables exist by using `isset()` or `empty()` before reading their value.)

To see what this outputs, put `console.log(data);` in the callback function in your `$.post()` call.

Comment: What's on and around line 10 in validate.php?

Comment: I have no idea why it couldn't run by using $name = $_POST['names'];

Comment: maybe I should return this in the ajax callback function html(data)?

Comment: it think instead of using ($name != 0), I should just write if($name)

Comment: `$name` was never defined in your original paste - hence the error. Let's try to keep things on SO as much as possible :)

Comment: why it was not defined? wasn't I declare $name = $_POST['name']; before it?

Comment: It was commented out ;)

Comment: no, even it wasn't, it still don't work, that's the author use $name = &$_POST['name'];

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37344/discussion-between-miguela-anthony-and-george-brighton)